# How we remove sounds from Video through SCPlayer?

Tags: audio

I am trying to remove Audio from Video and i am using SCRecorder Class.
but still there is Audio play. So Is there a way to remove Audio from Video using SCRecorder Class.I try following Code in my Project.

```
  SCRecorder *recorder = [SCRecorder recorder]; // You can also use +[SCRecorder sharedRecorder]
                        SCAudioConfiguration *audio = recorder.audioConfiguration;

                        // Whether the audio should be enabled or not
                        audio.enabled = NO;

                        [_player play];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN SCRecoder Class you need to stop or comment

this bunch of code

```
//        if (self.audioConfiguration.enabled) {
//            if (_audioOutput == nil) {
//                _audioOutput = [[AVCaptureAudioDataOutput alloc] init];
//                [_audioOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:_audioQueue];
//            }
//            
//            if ([session canAddOutput:_audioOutput]) {
//                [session addOutput:_audioOutput];
//                _audioOutputAdded = YES;
//            } else {
//                audioError = [SCRecorder createError:@"Cannot add audioOutput inside the sesssion"];
//            }
//        }
```

ann you find this code in below method

```
- (void)openSession:(void(^)(NSError *sessionError, NSError *audioError, NSError *videoError, NSError *photoError))completionHandler {
```